Facing build Issue in the MLC-LLM Android App
I've tried to run the MLC-LLM Android App with the below link, I can't able to run the app due to the error which is shown in the screenshot below:
Git Repository

I've cloned and runned the MLC-AI/MLC-LLC, but it's not running, I'm getting it, help me to fix this issue.
Did any one runned this for android, kindly help me to out in this.
In the directory of android, there are 3 folders:

mlc4j
MLCChat
MLCEngineExample

which one we need to use? how can i make work of it?

Thank you, I've fixed it. Actually I've missed to read some instruction they provided, so if any one facing this same kind of issue, please carefully read the below document clearly.
https://llm.mlc.ai/docs/deploy/android.html
